# Java compiling error, please help, i suck at java

Tags: java

Here is the error I get : 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor theController in class project******.theController cannot be applied to given types;

required: java.lang.String

found: int

reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method invocation conversion
at project*******.Main.main(Main.java:23)"

I know it tells me what the problem is, but how do I fix it?

Here is my code from my "Main",

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{


    readFile statesReadfile = new readFile();
    statesReadfile.loadData("States2.txt");
    theController statesQueues = new theController(statesReadfile.getNumStates());
    StatesStack myStatesStack = new StatesStack(statesReadfile.getNumStates());
```

and here is where I guess it doesn't match up with cause I have an error there too,

```
public class theController
{
 public Queues pq1; 
 public Queues pq3;
 public Queues pq5;
 public Queues pq6;
 private StatesStack stateArray;
 private readFile statesReadfile;
 /*
 * 
 */
 public theController(String filename) throws IOException
 {
    statesReadfile = new readFile();
    stateArray = statesReadfile.loadData(filename);

    pq1 = new Queues(6); 
    pq3 = new Queues(12);
    pq5 = new Queues(6);
    pq6 = new Queues(12);
  }// end of
```

any helpful suggestion will be much appreciated, thanks .

(oh and I do have more code if needed)

Comment: Never ever run a code that isn't compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you are passing to the `theController` constructor is an int but it should be a String in the line `theController statesQueues = new theController(statesReadfile.getNumStates());`

`getNumStates()` returns the number of states.

Comment: @hazerthanks I see what needs to happen, I just don't know how to do it, every time I change one thing something else turns red, but thanks any way for the input.